# look up if the characters in a string match the characters in a string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to achieve something like this:

const word = "abracadabra"
let usedCharacter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "r"]

if word consists of the available usedCharacter return true

let usedCharacter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "r", "z"] should also return true

let usedCharacter = ["b", "c", "d", "r", "z"]
should return false

should i iterate through word with a for loop and compare every word(i) with the used characters or is there an more easy way?

Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Yes, you'll need to check if each character is included in the array. A simple loop is fine and allows you to exit early if a character isn't found. You could also spread the string into an array and use `every()` – `[...word].every(char => usedCharacter.includes(char))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using `splitting` the word with each character and check if every character is there in `usedCharacter` or not.

```js
const word = "abracadabra";
const usedCharacter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "r"];

function hasAllUsedCharacters(word, used) {
  return word.split("").every((c) => usedCharacter.includes(c));
}

const result = hasAllUsedCharacters(word, usedCharacter);
console.log(result);
```

Alternate solution using [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const word = "abracadabra";
const usedCharacter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "r"];

function hasAllUsedCharacters(word, used) {
  const set = new Set(usedCharacter);
  const initialLength = set.size;
  word.split("").forEach((w) => set.add(w));

  return set.size === initialLength;
}

const result = hasAllUsedCharacters(word, usedCharacter);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! But what i do not understand yet is the the use of (c)

Comment: `c` is single character in `wordArray` after `splitting.`

Comment: your use of `set.add(...word)` is not adding all the characters of word, but only the first character. You would need to iterate over the word and add each character separately.

Comment: @pilchard What do you mean b `not adding all the characters`?

Comment: `Set.add()` only accepts a single value, so if you pass multiple values as you are with the spread, all but the first are ignored

Comment: Thanks, @pilchard Thank you so much. updated answer, There must be a method that adds all characters from iterable.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like this:

```
const word = "abracadabra";
let usedCharacter = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "r"];

let res = word.split('').filter(function(char) {
    return !usedCharacter.includes(char);
});
if(res.length == 0) {
     return true;
} else {
     return false;
}
```

this way you can know which characters are missing

good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps me to understand better!